# Switch IE9 browser mode to IE7 at runtime in VBA

Tags: internet-explorer-9, vba, internet-explorer-7, runtime

I want to switch the IE9 Browser mode to IE7 programmatically in VBA at runtime. I can engage the F12 develop tools and change it manually, but I want to automate this step in my code after I have opened my IE browser (defaulting to IE9).

Comment: I don't know, but my guess is this is not allowed, because it would be a security risk. You might be able, however, to write a program that changes IE's settings to always use IE7 mode before starting IE.

Comment: are you creating the web pages, or simply connection to them? If you are generating them, then adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />` to the header will force IE7 mode in IE8&9